# connecting "despite" with a clause

Tags: phrase-request

I know that the word "despite" goes well with nouns. For example,

> Even **despite** his usual **stubbornness**, he was still quite loyal this
> time.

or

> She refused to stay at home, even **despite** the **signs** of a coming storm
> in the sky.

However, I am not sure how to put this word smoothly with a whole clause. For example,

> Jack is an extremely friendly and chummy boy. Even **despite** his passive
> **vocabulary is not great** and his comprehension is rather low he is
> always ready to participate in class in one way or another and provide
> any help.

Something doesn't feel right about it.
What would be the natural way to do it here?

Comment: The words **even** and **despite** don't go together. When you use **despite**, omit **even**. You could write **Despite the fact that..** but this is unnecessarily wordy. Far better just to say **Although his...** or **Even though his...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Despite* doesn't go well together with *even* to show a surprising contrast.

> **Despite the fact that/In spite of the fact that** his passive vocabulary is not great and his comprehension is rather low, ...

> **Despite of/In spite of** [him] having a small vocabulary and comprehending things slowly, ...

Personally, I would use

> **Even though/Though/Although** his passive vocabulary is not great, ...

You can rewrite the given clauses.

- "his passive vocabulary is not great" might be "his poor/restricted/limited/small/narrow? passive vocabulary";
- "his comprehension is rather low" might be "his limited/poor comprehension" or stronger "his lack of comprehension".